# AngularJS ng-click doesn't work with mobile chrome browser

Tags: android, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, mobile-chrome

I have a problem with ng-click. On my desktop computer, erverything works fine. But when I try the same on my android mobile phone the ng-click doesn't work. Strange is, that it works with the standart browser from android, but with chrome it doesn't. Is there any option, which I can set or unset?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Update your chrome browser. I guess It is issue with the browser.

Comment: version of android?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I reinstalled chroem and now it works.